# '+': no implicit conversation of fixnum into array <TypeError>

Tags: ruby

В командной строке выходит ошибка

```
    '+': no implicit conversation of fixnum into array <TypeError>
    from test.rb:117:in 'block <main>'
    from test.rb:107:in 'each'
    from test.rb:107:in '<main>'
```

Ниже строки 107-119:

```
for item in questions_yes do 
puts item
user_input = nil

while (user_input != "yes" and user_input !="no" )
puts "#{name}, введите ответ yes или no"
user_input = STDIN.gets.chomp.downcase
end

if (user_input == "yes")
    correct_answers += 1
end
end
```

Comment: А `correct_answers` у вас не массив, случаем?

Comment: Спасибо, VenZell. Оказалось, что был массив, убрал квадратные скобки, и все прекрасно заработало

Comment: Пожалуйста. Я оформил свой комментарий в виде ответа. Если он помог вам, отметьте его верным, пожалуйста.

Comment: FYI: в Ruby принято пользоваться `array.each do |i|` вместо `for i in array do`.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь сложить массив с целым числом вот в этой строчке:

```
correct_answers += 1
```